# Работа с set'ами. Костыли. Имея набор попарных связей, определить связаны ли два заданных узла

Tags: python, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Доброго времени суток, друзья. Прошу помочь устранить костыль в коде.

Задача следующая:

Дан массив прямых связей (пары), нужно определить, имеют ли общие связи две выделенные переменные. Думаю по картинке станет яснее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Определить, имеют ли связи dr101 и super.

Прикладываю своё решение. Код рабочий.

```
def check_connection(network, first, second):
    first_set = set() 
    second_set = set()

    for couple in network: 
                    #Разбиваю массив на два отдельных имени(слова)
        couple_word = couple.split('-')

        if len(first_set) == 0: 
                    #Вот как избавится от данного костыля, не пойму.
                    #Чтобы сравнить следующие имена, нужна непустая коллекция
            first_set.add(couple_word[0]), first_set.add(couple_word[1])
        else:
            if couple_word[0] in first_set or couple_word[1] in first_set:
                    #Если хотя бы одно имя из пары уже есть в коллекции,
                    #То добавляем второе в коллекцию
                first_set.add(couple_word[0]),first_set.add(couple_word[1])

            else:
                    #Если "Знакомых" имен в коллекции не нашлось
                    #Отправляем во вторую коллекцию
                second_set.add(couple_word[0]), second_set.add(couple_word[1])


    if (first in first_set and second in first_set) or (first in second_set and second in second_set):
                    #Тоже написано криво, на мой взгляд, однако не получилось сократить
                    #first,second in ____set - выдает ошибку
        print("Они знакомы")
        return True
    else:
        print("Они не знакомы")
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert check_connection(
        ("dr101-mr99", "mr99-out00", "dr101-out00", "scout1-scout2",
         "scout3-scout1", "scout1-scout4", "scout4-sscout", "sscout-super"),
        "scout2", "scout3") == True, "Scout Brotherhood"
    assert check_connection(
        ("dr101-mr99", "mr99-out00", "dr101-out00", "scout1-scout2",
         "scout3-scout1", "scout1-scout4", "scout4-sscout", "sscout-super"),
        "super", "scout2") == True, "Super Scout"
    assert check_connection(
        ("dr101-mr99", "mr99-out00", "dr101-out00", "scout1-scout2",
         "scout3-scout1", "scout1-scout4", "scout4-sscout", "sscout-super"),
        "dr101", "sscout") == False, "I don't know any scouts."
    assert check_connection(("out00-scout3","mega-scout3","mega-robin",),"robin","out00") == True
```

В комментариях кода, постарался изложить решение, и те моменты, которые для меня на данный момент моих знаний, написано плохо.

Большое спасибо.

Comment: В вашей задаче нужно определить есть ли прямая связь (длиной 1, непосредственно между вершинами) или непрямая (с промежуточными вершинами)?

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, в задаче речь идет о непрямой связи. Проще говоря, как раздел "Друзья", в социальных сетях, т.е : если У вас в друзьях есть Иван Иванов, и этот же человек есть у меня, то по задумке данной задачи, мы с вами "знакомы"(можем увидеть друг друга в списке "Друзья друзей", результат нашей связи будет True

Comment: пробовали ваш код с графом, в котором больше двух связных компонент (больше двух наборов вершин, которые связаны между собой)?

Comment: Нет, на сколько я понял из условии задачи, наборов вершин будет две. При большем количестве вершин, этот код, конечно, работать не будет

Comment: Количество наборов вершин никак в условии не ограничено. К примеру: `edges=("a-b", "c-d", "e-f", "a-h")` содержит три набора (три связных компоненты). [`b` и `h` соединены](http://ideone.com/Q9MoYA), а [`d` и `e` не соединены](http://ideone.com/4l7zK7). Ваш [код возвращает, что `d` и `e` соединены](http://ideone.com/cHl4Iw). Не используйте метку [tag:инспекция-кода] для сломанного кода.

Comment: [вот картинка графа для наглядности](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnyfM.png) (три набора)

Comment: Да, пожалуй я неверно указал условия задачи. Количество наборов для проверки конкретно этой задачи - два.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Super Scout" пример в вопросе, который требует наличия соединения между super и scout2, говорит, что задача не только "друзья друзей" найти:

[image: graph]

Задача вероятно определить соединены ли две вершины в графе, заданном ребрами:

```
import networkx as nx  # $ pip install networkx

def connected(edges, a, b):
    """Whether *a* and *b* vertices are connected in the graph with *edges*."""
    G = nx.Graph(edge.split('-') for edge in edges)
    return nx.has_path(G, a, b)
```

Пример:

```
>>> connected(
...        ("dr101-mr99", "mr99-out00", "dr101-out00", "scout1-scout2",
...         "scout3-scout1", "scout1-scout4", "scout4-sscout", "sscout-super"),
...        "super", "scout2")
True
```

Если хочется самостоятельно реализовать, то прямолинейным подходом является алгоритм схожий с [поиском в ширину (BFS)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83):

```
from collections import defaultdict


def connected(edges, a, b):
    # create adjacency lists for the graph
    G = defaultdict(list)  # vertex -> neighbors
    for edge in edges:
        v, u = edge.split('-')
        G[v].append(u)
        G[u].append(v)

    # visit all vertices connected to *a* until *b* is found
    vertices = set([a])
    visited = set()
    while vertices:
        v = vertices.pop()
        visited.add(v)
        if v == b:
            return True  # there is a path from *a* to *b*
        vertices.update(u for u in G[v] if u not in visited)
    return False  # *a* and *b* are not connected
```